# Have outer div scroll past div inside it with css

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div inside another div which has a fixed position at the bottom of the page. I need the outer div to scroll all the way past the inner div allowing all the content to be shown.

```
.outer{position:relative; }
.inner{position:fixed; bottom:0; z-index:999;}

<div class="outer">
  <p>Lots of content......</p>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>More content fixed in a box at the bottom of the page.....</p>
    </div>
 <div>
```

Maybe this well help describe it better- http://jsfiddle.net/winchendonsprings/dDgjQ/2/
What I need in this example is the yellow text to scroll all the way to the top of the red box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add some `padding` to the bottom of the `div.outer` and adjust as necessary for the size of the red `div`.

In this instance, I did `padding-bottom:100px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dDgjQ/3/

**EDIT**

To respond to your comment re `div.inner` not appearing on each page, you could do the following with jQuery:

`$('.inner').parent().css('paddingBottom','100px');`

Here it is applied:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dDgjQ/4/

And here it is with the `div.inner` removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dDgjQ/5/

**EDIT 2**

You could also create another class and only add it to that page.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/dDgjQ/6/

Comment: I forgot to mention, This inner div will not be on every page, only one page actually. However, the outer div will be on every page. If I add the padding it will be visible on page where it will look funny. Know of a work-around?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. My solution was basically your EDIT 2. Thanks again